# Compiled C++ build doesn't output nor provide error

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using cmake and mingw32-make to build my C++ SDL2 project called **`Something`**.
After I did `cmake .` it generated few folders and files, where I went inside the build folder. It had a make file, so I used `make` in that directory.
Then it generated my executable which should be `something.exe`. It did, but when I try to run the executable it provides no errors or output. When I try to compile without including `SDL.h` and commenting the sdl code, it outputs `Initialized` which should appear even with including `SDl.h`.
This is my project directory

```
Something
  |
  |
  |---- SDL2
  |       |
  |       |---- include
  |       |
  |       |---- lib
  |
  ---- src
  |     |
  |     |---- something.cpp
  |
  |
  |---- CMakeLists.txt
```

This is my cmake file

```
# cmake version to be used
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.8.0 )
project(something VERSION 1.0.0)

set(SDL2_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2/")

set(SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS "${SDL2_DIR}/include")


# Support both 32 and 64 bit builds
if (${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P} MATCHES 8)
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${SDL2_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2main.lib;${SDL2_DIR}/lib/x64/SDL2.lib")
else ()
    set(SDL2_LIBRARIES "${SDL2_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2main.lib;${SDL2_DIR}/lib/x86/SDL2.lib")
endif ()

# link dependencies
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

# link dependencies
include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

# Project files and linking
set(SOURCES src/something.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/something.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})
```

And finally this is my `src/something.cpp`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int agrc, char* agrs[]){
    std::cout << "Initialized!!" << std::endl;  
    
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;

    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0 ){
            std::cout << "Error : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
            return -1;
    }    
    
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Something", 50, 50, 700, 500, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

    SDL_Delay(1000);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "when I try to run the executable it provides no errors or output." - Probably it cannot find dynamic (`.dll`) SDL library at **runtime**. Normally you need to have `.dll` libraries in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: @Tsyvarev oh wait let me try that, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tsyvarev that actually worked!!

Comment: Probably you tried to run it from the terminal, or using the IDE. If you try to start it from the explorer with a double-click, it might display a proper error explaining what `.dll`s are missing, which wouldn't be displayed otherwise.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, i was runing it from terminal, so i didn't get output or errors, but yeah the fact was i was missing the `dlls` thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must not forget to put the `.dll`(dynamic link libraries) in the same directory as the executable in order for the executable to work